# Using the comma operator with the conditional operator

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, comma-operator

I am learning C++ and stumbled upong the following behaviour when using the `,` and `?:` operators. The conditional operator has a syntax like this `E1 ? E2 : E3`, where E1, E2 and E3 are expressions[1],[2]. I started with this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 20, y = 25;
    x > y ? cout << "x > y\n" , cout << "x is greater than y" : cout << "x !> y\n", cout << "x is not greater than y";
    return 0;
}
```

and outputs:

```
x !> y
x is not greater than y
```

which is the result I was expecting. But when I change the values to `int x = 25, y = 20` so that x is greater than y, I get the following output:

```
x > y
x is greater than y
x is not greater than y
```

but I was expecting:

```
x > y
x is greater than y
```

so the final part of expression `E3` is being computed even when the result of expression `E1` was `true`.

However, when I put E2 and E3 inside parenthesis, the output of the programm is as expected for both cases: when x > y and when x < y. According to [1], the comma `,` is on operator with operands E1 and E2 as in `E1, E2`, which is an expression itself, by [1]. Based on this, I do not understand why the final part of expression E3 for the `?:` operator is being computed even when the expression `E1` is true and both.

My questions are:

1) Am I correctly using the conditional operator `?:`?

2) What is the mechanism by which this unexpected result is happening?

3) Why does the use parenthesis solves the issue (or at least agrees with my expectation)?

I am working with: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)

Thank you very much.

[1]https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions

[2]https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: You can output two things without using the comma operator: `cout << one << two`. This is how the "streaming" operator `<<` was designed. Using this is idiomatic, so it's better than adding parentheses.

Comment: With operator precedence (or grammar rule): `cond ? E1, E2 : E3, E4;` is equivalent to `(cond ? (E1, E2) : E3), E4;`.

Comment: @Fer Isn't the answer you've gotten sufficient? Your question is still left open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity let's consider a statement that is easier to read:

```cpp
foo ? a(), b() : c(), d();
```

The first operator we encounter is the conditional operator ([§7.6.16](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond)):

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

The second operand can be an expression and `a(), b()` is a compound expression.
The third operand however can only be an assignment-expression ([§7.6.19](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#nt:assignment-expression)):

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    yield-expression
    throw-expression
    logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
assignment-operator: one of
    =  *=  /=  %=   +=  -=  >>=  <<=  &=  ^=  |=
```

```cpp
c(), d()
```

is not one of those but a comma-expression (§[7.6.20/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.comma-1)):

```
expression:
    assignment-expression
    expression , assignment-expression
```

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded-value expression. Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression. *[...]*

So everything on the left side of the last comma operator in the whole statement is a discarded-value expression that gets computed (and its result discarded) before the right side of the comma operator.

Comment: Does this mean that the expression `d()` is, in deed, not  "seen" as an operand of the `?:` conditional operator, but instead simply seen as  another expression that the programmer (myself) happend to write by use of the comma operator?  In other words, it is being interpreted as in the following block of code?

`x > y ? cout << "x > y\n" , cout << "x is greater than y" : cout << "x !> y\n"; 
cout << "x is not greater than y";`

@J. Doe thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: *In other words, it is being interpreted as in the following block of code?* – yes